# from request $ _GET to folder

Tags: php, dynamic

I have a website with a dynamic structure: for every `$_GET['action']` I include a file with a different content, while the footer and the header always remain the same. example: `www.mysite.com/index.php?action=service1` 
I would like to change this "structure" in a way:
`www.mysite.com/service1/` is there a way to include the `$_GET['action']` request in every folder I create?

The site in question has over 100+ `$_GET['action']` and creating a page for each action would become heavy .

any advice on how to do?

Comment: Yeah, my advice is to use a CMS like Wordpress or Joomla!  This is a very solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your .htaccess to pipe certain values to your $_GET variables.

Learn more [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049).

The basic idea is to add something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^service/(\d+).*$ ./myActionscript.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then all requests you send to /service/{number} will go to your file myActionScript and you can do what you want with that {number} there by using string manipulation on the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get it.